# Angular 7 - Mudar a cor da checkbox após marcar como checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Eu tenho a seguinte lista de checkboxes:

[image: Lista de checkboxes]

Estou usando Bootstrap 4 e Angular 7.
Gostaria de saber uma maneira de que quando a checkbox for clicada, a linha dela mude de cor, assim fica mais fácil do usuário saber se está clicando nas permissões certas (Leitura, Impressão, Exclusão e Gravação).

EDIT: Código do HTML

```html
<div id="test-l-4" class="content">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="funcionalidade">Funcionalidades</label>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check " *ngFor="let f of funcionalidades; let x = index">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="{{ f.id_funcionalidade }}">{{ f.id_funcionalidade }} - {{ f.nome_funcionalidade }}
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right" *ngFor="let op of operacoes; let i = index">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkinfo_{{x}}_{{i}}" >{{op.operacao}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button (click)="back()" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Back</button>
          <button (click)="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Cara isso da pra fazer com CSS, nem precisa de js... Coloca ai seu html e CSS tbm

Comment: @hugocsl postei o html para vcs darem uma olhada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como havia comentado, vc pode usar a pseudo classe `:checked` e o seletor `+` para pegar a `div` irmã direta do `checkbox` e colocar uma cor de background nela

Basicamente vc vai precisar dessa regra CSS

```
.form-check-input:checked + div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
.form-check-input:checked + div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="test-l-4" class="content">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="funcionalidade">Funcionalidades</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-check " *ngFor="let f of funcionalidades; let x = index">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                        id="{{ f.id_funcionalidade }}">{{ f.id_funcionalidade }} - {{ f.nome_funcionalidade }}
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right"
                        *ngFor="let op of operacoes; let i = index">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkinfo_{{x}}_{{i}}">{{op.operacao}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check " *ngFor="let f of funcionalidades; let x = index">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                        id="{{ f.id_funcionalidade }}">{{ f.id_funcionalidade }} - {{ f.nome_funcionalidade }}
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right"
                        *ngFor="let op of operacoes; let i = index">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkinfo_{{x}}_{{i}}">{{op.operacao}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check " *ngFor="let f of funcionalidades; let x = index">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                        id="{{ f.id_funcionalidade }}">{{ f.id_funcionalidade }} - {{ f.nome_funcionalidade }}
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right"
                        *ngFor="let op of operacoes; let i = index">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkinfo_{{x}}_{{i}}">{{op.operacao}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="back()" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Back</button>
    <button (click)="next()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @hugocsl, funcionou como eu pedi! Vlw!

Comment: @EdwardRamos sem problemas meu caro, tem coisas simples que da para fazer com CSS que vc nem acredita que não tem script envolvido rss. []´s

Comment: É verdade. Com esse código, até fiz um "hover", e ficou bom também.