# Questionário de múltipla escolha Efeito Fade

Tags: jquery, css

Em questionário de múltipla escolha (opções de 1 a 10), estou tentando fazer o efeito em que a questão fica com opacidade baixa de início, mas, quando ela recebe o focus ou o click, independentemente da questão, ela fica com opacidade 1. Ainda não consegui fazer. Estou usando radio buttom. Alguém sabe como posso fazer?

Exemplo:https://pt.surveymonkey.com/r/LYZL3KQ

```html
<form id="formulario" name="form" method="post">   
    <div id="quiz01">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-2">1. O formato do <strong>Livro Digital</strong> melhorou a minha experiência de aprendizagem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle box-numeros" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-light mr-2 border">1<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao01" value="1" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">2<input type="radio" class="opcao02" name="avaliacao01" value="2" /></label>
                    <label
                        class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">3<input type="radio" class="opcao03" name="avaliacao01" value="3" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">4<input type="radio" class="opcao04" name="avaliacao01" value="4" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">5<input type="radio" class="opcao05" name="avaliacao01" value="5" /></label>
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">6<input type="radio" class="opcao06" name="avaliacao01" value="6" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">7<input type="radio" class="opcao07" name="avaliacao01" value="7" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">8<input type="radio" class="opcao08" name="avaliacao01" value="8" /></label>
                            <label
                                class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">9<input type="radio" class="opcao09" name="avaliacao01" value="9" /></label><label class="btn btn-light ml-2 border">10<input type="radio" class="opcao10" name="avaliacao01" value="10" /></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-5">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Discordo plenamente</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p class="text-right mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Concordo plenamente<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="quiz02">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-2">2. A função <strong>Notas e Destaques</strong><img class="imagem" src="https://cm-kls-content.s3.amazonaws.com/DESEN_WEBAULA/BOOTSTRAP/img/formulario/icones-02.png" /> melhora o meu processo de estudo.<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle box-numeros" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-light mr-2 border">1<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="1" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">2<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="2" /></label>
                    <label
                        class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">3<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="3" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">4<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="4" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">5<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="5" /></label>
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">6<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="6" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">7<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="7" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">8<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="8" /></label>
                            <label
                                class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">9<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="9" /></label><label class="btn btn-light ml-2 border">10<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="10" /></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-5">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Discordo plenamente</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p class="text-right mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Concordo plenamente<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</form>
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta um [mcve].

Comment: Olha a resposta dessa pergunta, no lugar do `checked` seria um `hover` no seu caso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376161/angular-7-mudar-a-cor-da-checkbox-ap%c3%b3s-marcar-como-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, basta você buscar a div principal do grupo de radiobuttons com id que começa com `quiz` e alterar a opacidade para 1.

Por exemplo, ao clicar num radio, você busca a div com `.closest()`:

```
.closest("[id^=quiz]")
```

Onde o id começa com a palavra "quiz", porque cada div de pergunta tem em comum os id's que começam com essa palavra: `quiz01`, `quiz02` etc., e o operador `^=` busca o elemento cujo atributo começa com a palavra especificada, no caso, "quiz".

Para pegar o click no radio, é a mesma coisa, só que usando o atributo `class`:

```
$(":radio[class^=opcao]").on("click", function(){...
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$(":radio[class^=opcao]").on("click", function(){
   $(this)                 // elemento radio clicado
   .closest("[id^=quiz]")  // busca o primeiro ancestral cujo id começa com "quiz"
   .css("opacity", "1");   // altera a opacidade
});
```

```css
[id^=quiz]{
   opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" name="form" method="post">   
    <div id="quiz01">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-2">1. O formato do <strong>Livro Digital</strong> melhorou a minha experiência de aprendizagem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle box-numeros" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-light mr-2 border">1<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao01" value="1" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">2<input type="radio" class="opcao02" name="avaliacao01" value="2" /></label>
                    <label
                        class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">3<input type="radio" class="opcao03" name="avaliacao01" value="3" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">4<input type="radio" class="opcao04" name="avaliacao01" value="4" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">5<input type="radio" class="opcao05" name="avaliacao01" value="5" /></label>
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">6<input type="radio" class="opcao06" name="avaliacao01" value="6" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">7<input type="radio" class="opcao07" name="avaliacao01" value="7" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">8<input type="radio" class="opcao08" name="avaliacao01" value="8" /></label>
                            <label
                                class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">9<input type="radio" class="opcao09" name="avaliacao01" value="9" /></label><label class="btn btn-light ml-2 border">10<input type="radio" class="opcao10" name="avaliacao01" value="10" /></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-5">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Discordo plenamente</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p class="text-right mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Concordo plenamente<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="quiz02">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-2">2. A função <strong>Notas e Destaques</strong><img class="imagem" src="https://cm-kls-content.s3.amazonaws.com/DESEN_WEBAULA/BOOTSTRAP/img/formulario/icones-02.png" /> melhora o meu processo de estudo.<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle box-numeros" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-light mr-2 border">1<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="1" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">2<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="2" /></label>
                    <label
                        class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">3<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="3" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">4<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="4" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">5<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="5" /></label>
                        <label
                            class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">6<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="6" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">7<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="7" /></label><label class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">8<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="8" /></label>
                            <label
                                class="btn btn-light mx-2 border">9<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="9" /></label><label class="btn btn-light ml-2 border">10<input type="radio" class="opcao01" name="avaliacao02" value="10" /></label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-5">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Discordo plenamente</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p class="text-right mb-0 texto-form-cinza">Concordo plenamente<br /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</form>
```

Se você quiser um efeito de transição, pode usar:

```
.animate({opacity: 1});
```

No lugar de:

```
.css("opacity", "1");
```

Comment: Sam no casodo seu ele pega o radio, no meu ele fica active o label como posso trocar?

Comment: Tenta isso: `$(".box-numeros label").on("click", function(){` no lugar disso: `$(":radio[class^=opcao]").on("click", function(){`

Comment: Funcionou \o, agora eu preciso fazer ele fica com opacity 1 a questão conforme rolo o scroll sabe como posso fazer isto?